# Не получается изменить тип build в unity 5?

Tags: unity3d

В Unity 5 нет типа Unity Web Player в разделе build. Хотя сам  Unity Web Player в систему я поставил и установил в систему новую версию Unity - вместо 5.4 версию 5.5, но проблема не решилась.

Comment: Смотри в сторону WebGL ..... добавил в ответ ссылку из блога https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Браузеры наплевали нагло на weplayer и не поддерживают нифига. Или, как минимум, уже скоро окончательно прекратят поддерживать. Хром давно забил и не воспроизводит. Поэтому Unity >= 5.4 больше не включает такую опцию.

Если нужна возможность, то придется работать с Unity версией 5.3 и ниже

Но вообще, нужно перебираться на WebGL. Собственно, оно всю малину и испортило))) Типа будущее, все дела.

Можно инфу [из блога юнити](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/) еще глянуть чо каво